# Does python unittest framework test runner run in a separate thread?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, python-unittest

I am trying to figure out the order in which Python unittest framework executes, as I need to know in order to get tests for a multithreaded application to pass correctly.
Does the test runner, (which calls all functions labelled `test_*`) run in a separate thread?

If not, what is the order in which the program executes? I know `setup()` is called first, is the first function named `test_*` called immediately after? Or is there something else in between?

Comment: Your tests shouldn't depend on any particular execution order.

Comment: `setup` is called "first", in the sense that it is executed before *each* test method is called. You shouldn't carry state between test methods; anything a particular test method needs should be intialized by `setup`.